# How do I move a docker container's image to a persistent disk?

Tags: docker, lxc, persistent-storage, linux-containers

We have noticed that our containers are taking up a lot of space, one of the reasons for this is the images.

We would like to move the images.

I know right now they are stored in 
**`/var/lib/docker/graph/<id>/layer`**

**Is there a way to move these to another location/persistent disk?**

Comment: please, if you find a response useful, just flag it green ;-)

Answer (score 30):

To move images to another drive or another server:

```
docker save image_name > image_name.tar

mv image_name.tar /somewhere/else/
```

Load it back into docker

```
docker load < image_name.tar
```

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/).

Comment: When you load the image back, does it take space on your drive so you have to move it again?

Answer (score 23):

Here's any easy way to move docker's data:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /a/new/location
sudo ln -s /a/new/location /var/lib/docker # Create a symbolic link
sudo service docker start
```

No need to change `DOCKER_OPTS` or use `-g /path`.

Answer (score 17):

You can always mount /var/lib/docker to a different disk. Otherwise, you can start the daemon with `-g /path` in order to tell docker to use a different directory for storage.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [answer by @creack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21488513/350933) I did the following on my Ubuntu install to move my entire docker images/containers folder to a new location/disk.  The great thing about doing this is that any new images that I install will then use the new disk location.

First stop the docker service:

```
sudo service docker stop
```

Then move the docker folder from the default location to your target location:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /thenewlocation
```

Then edit the `/etc/default/docker` file, inserting/amending the following line which provides the new location as an argument for the docker service:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-g /thenewlocation/docker"
```

Restart the docker service:

```
sudo service docker start
```

This worked 100% for me - all my images remained in tact.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: I added the location as in answer, but whenever I restart docker, it creates `/var/lib/docker` anew. And when I execute `ps aux | grep docker`, I see the process doesn't have the `-g /foo` arg that was added in config file.

Comment: So, the `-g` option I confirm that works. Inserting `-g /foo` into the `docker.service` file works for me. That's not a good option though as update will likely overwrite that file.

Comment: Alright, I found: you have to create a file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with this content `{ "data-root": "/my/path" }`, then restart docker. Although you won't see any changes in `ps aux`, but docker does use the `/my/path` this way, and the older `/var/lib/docker` will not be re-created if you deleted it beforehand.