# AEM is installed under /var in DOCKER , I need to move the same to /opt as I am facing space issue

Tags: docker, aem

We have docker. And our AEM (CQ) instance is installed in a docker container with image under /var. Now my instance is not writing to disk due to space issue under /var.
Can anyone please let me know the steps to stop the instance and create the same image at /opt and start the CQ instance.

There is Nirmata as well in our servers. This Docker and Nirmata is very new to me, hence I will be needing any one of your help, to move the aem instance to /opt

I am seeing the below errors in log :

> 28.12.2015 06:37:43.178 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-2] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null
>       28.12.2015 06:37:43.701 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-3] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.sling.discovery.impl.common.heartbeat.HeartbeatHandler@46fd4e4a : null
>       28.12.2015 06:37:48.178 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-2] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null
>       28.12.2015 06:37:53.177 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-4] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null
>       28.12.2015 06:37:58.178 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-3] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null
>       28.12.2015 06:38:03.178 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-3] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null
>       28.12.2015 06:38:08.178 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-1] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null
>       28.12.2015 06:38:13.178 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-4] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null
>       28.12.2015 06:38:13.701 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-1] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.sling.discovery.impl.common.heartbeat.HeartbeatHandler@46fd4e4a : null
>       28.12.2015 06:38:18.178 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-3] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null
>       28.12.2015 06:38:20.703 *ERROR* [10.127.243.106 [1451284700699] POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.servlets.ReplicationServlet Error during replication: null
>       28.12.2015 06:38:23.178 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-2] org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler Exception during job execution of org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.AsyncIndexUpdate@3142f237 : null

Answer (score 0):

Docker will use the graph directory below it's root directory (/var/lib/docker/graph) to store the images. Therefore you need to either change the location or replace that directory by a symlink to your new location. The following post covers two potential solutions
[Moving docker root folder to a new drive / partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258458/moving-docker-root-folder-to-a-new-drive-partition)